# tableView won't reload number of rows

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm creating a `tableView` with 7 rows (days of week).
After tapping `month` button I'm changing variable from `week` to `month` and reloading table data from click event function.
Data are reloaded but a number of rows is not changing.

Here is my code

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        var rowNumber = 0
        if self.dateInnerState == "week" || self.dateInnerState == "" {
            rowNumber = 7
        } else if self.dateInnerState == "month" {
            rowNumber = self.currentMonthDays.count
        } else {
            rowNumber = 12
        }
        print(">>>>", rowNumber, self.dateInnerState)
        return rowNumber
    }
```

this is what a method above prints after `month` button pressed

```
>>>> 30 month
```

Also data inside of table are changed, but the number or rows stays at 7...

Comment: Maybe your setting the rowHeight as well, and you need to scroll to see the other rows?

Comment: there was rowHeight set! thanks, this worked!

Comment: Just a style note; you should use an `enum` for your week/month selection rather than strings.

Answer (score -1):

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

 @IBOutlet weak var tbl: UITableView!
 var dateInnerState = "week"

   override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     self.tbl.rowHeight = 50
   }

   @IBAction func btnMClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        if dateInnerState == "week" {
            dateInnerState = "month"
        } else {
            dateInnerState = "week"
        }
        
        self.tbl.reloadData()
  }

}

extension ViewController : UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        var rowNumber = 0
                if self.dateInnerState == "week" || self.dateInnerState == "" {
                    rowNumber = 7
                } else if self.dateInnerState == "month" {
                    rowNumber = 30
                } else {
                    rowNumber = 12
                }
                print(">>>>", rowNumber, self.dateInnerState)
                return rowNumber
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell") as? TableViewCell {
            
            cell.lbl.text = "\(indexPath.row)"
            return cell
        }
        
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}

--------------

import UIKit

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    
    @IBOutlet var lbl : UILabel!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```